# How can I re-scan for a Bluetooth LE peripheral once it disconnects from my iOS app?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I have a small iOS app that connects to a cB−OLP425i−26-A made by connectBlue.
I have it displaying the battery of the module as well as other things.

When I get too far away from the module it disconnects and I get the following error

CBUUID:  E2ED3400-5650-3314-C2A8-C93508AFA475, ERROR: The connection has timed out unexpectedly.

I would like to have the app to continue to scan for the peripheral and reconnect when it gets within range.  I can't seemed to be able to do this. I have tried inserting an if/else statement where as if the module is not connected a text field says "Disconnected" and if connected "Connected".  Then I say if the text field says "Disconnected" the app should scan.  This didn't work.

I also put into the when disconnected the [view setNeedsDisplay] and then put everything into the viewWillAppear animated   Still no luck.

Can anyone explain what I should do or what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

```
[self stopScan] in didRetrievePeripherals
```

and

```
[central stopScan] in didConnectPeripheral
```

added doesn't rescan or reconnect

then added

```
[self startScan] in didDisconnectPeripheral
```

rescans and reconnects but app crashes because of

```
- (void)startScan
{NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:FALSE], CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey, nil];
    [manager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:self.dicoveredPeripherals options:options];
}
```

and

and this error message in debugger

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid Object', reason: 'Argument  E2ED3400-5650-3314-C2A8-C93508AFA475, Name = "OBP425-0B32", IsConnected = NO> is invalid'

when the app disconnects this is the whole error

Did Disconnect to peripheral:  E2ED3400-5650-3314-C2A8-C93508AFA475, Name = "OBP425-0B32", IsConnected = NO> with error = The connection has timed out unexpectedly.

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Do you call a `stopScan`?
I suggest that in the delegate method: `centralManager:didDisconnectPeripheral:error:` you start a scan if you stopped it previously.

Comment: Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: Ok got it working  I had to set the discoveredPeripheral to nil in didRetrievePeripherals  Thanks a lot for the help.  Now all I have to do is it do the rescanning in the background.  I have set the info.plist to app Communicates using CoreBluetooth for Required background modes but this rescan doesn't work in background.  any suggestions  I will create a separate post.